# UTC is incorrect in my Elementary OS

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, elementary-os

My BIOS time is matched to local time(ie IST). When I run "date -u"  in terminal, it shows a time 1 hours faster than my BIOS time(ie IST+1h). And that's why my system time is wrong. 
How to correct UTC?

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward fix: Set the RTC to UTC. This is only a problem when you run a dual boot system with Windows:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot

Yes, that is about Ubuntu, but I guess it can be applied to Elementary OS, too. And of course lots of other ressources on that issue can be found in the web.

Also related, but lacking an accepted answer, or one as complete as the previous one:

[Different time in Windows and Linux Mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52423/different-time-in-windows-and-linux-mint/52429#52429)